# How to find out whether a member function is const or volatile with libclang?

Tags: c++, c, clang, libclang

I have an instance of `CXCursor` of kind `CXCursor_CXXMethod`. I want to find out if the function is `const` or `volatile`, for example:

```
class Foo {
public:
    void bar() const;
    void baz() volatile;
    void qux() const volatile;
};
```

I could not find anything useful in the documentation of libclang. I tried `clang_isConstQualifiedType` and `clang_isVolatileQualifiedType` but these always seem to return `0` on C++ member function types.

Comment: Is a `C++` solution acceptable, or only `C` ?

Comment: A C++ solution is acceptable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I can think of two approaches:

**Using the `libclang` lexer**

The code which appears in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11738120/1071136) works for me; it uses the `libclang` tokenizer to break a method declaration apart, and then records any keywords outside of the method parentheses.

It does *not* access the AST of the code, and as far as I can tell doesn't involve the parser at all. If you are sure the code you investigate is proper C++, I believe this approach is safe.

*Disadvantages*: This solution does not appear to take into account preprocessing directives, so the code has to be processed first (e.g., passed through `cpp`).

Example code (the file to parse must be the first argument to your program, e.g. `./a.out bla.cpp`):

```
#include "clang-c/Index.h"
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

std::string GetClangString(CXString str)
{
  const char* tmp = clang_getCString(str);
  if (tmp == NULL) {
    return "";
  } else {
    std::string translated = std::string(tmp);
    clang_disposeString(str);
    return translated;
  }
}

void GetMethodQualifiers(CXTranslationUnit translationUnit,
                         std::set<std::string>& qualifiers,
                         CXCursor cursor) {
  qualifiers.clear();

  CXSourceRange range = clang_getCursorExtent(cursor);
  CXToken* tokens;
  unsigned int numTokens;
  clang_tokenize(translationUnit, range, &tokens, &numTokens);

  bool insideBrackets = false;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numTokens; i++) {
    std::string token = GetClangString(clang_getTokenSpelling(translationUnit, tokens[i]));
    if (token == "(") {
      insideBrackets = true;
    } else if (token == "{" || token == ";") {
      break;
    } else if (token == ")") {
      insideBrackets = false;
    } else if (clang_getTokenKind(tokens[i]) == CXToken_Keyword && 
             !insideBrackets) {
      qualifiers.insert(token);
    }
  }

  clang_disposeTokens(translationUnit, tokens, numTokens);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  CXIndex Index = clang_createIndex(0, 0);
  CXTranslationUnit TU = clang_parseTranslationUnit(Index, 0, 
          argv, argc, 0, 0, CXTranslationUnit_None);

  // Set the file you're interested in, and the code location:
  CXFile file = clang_getFile(TU, argv[1]);
  int line = 5;
  int column = 6;
  CXSourceLocation location = clang_getLocation(TU, file, line, column);
  CXCursor cursor = clang_getCursor(TU, location);

  std::set<std::string> qualifiers;
  GetMethodQualifiers(TU, qualifiers, cursor);

  for (std::set<std::string>::const_iterator i = qualifiers.begin(); i != qualifiers.end(); ++i) {
    std::cout << *i << std::endl;
  }

  clang_disposeTranslationUnit(TU);
  clang_disposeIndex(Index);
  return 0;
}
```

**Using `libclang`'s Unified Symbol Resolution (USR)**

This approach involves using the parser itself, and extracting qualifier information from the AST.

*Advantages*: Seems to work for code with preprocessor directives, at least for simple cases.

*Disadvantages*: My solution parses the USR, which is undocumented, and might change in the future. Still, it's easy to write a unit-test to guard against that.

Take a look at `$(CLANG_SRC)/tools/libclang/CIndexUSRs.cpp`, it contains the code that generates a USR, and therefore contains the information required to parse the USR string. Specifically, lines 523-529 (in LLVM 3.1's source downloaded from [www.llvm.org](http://www.llvm.org)) for the qualifier part.

Add the following function somewhere:

```
void parseUsrString(const std::string& usrString, bool* isVolatile, bool* isConst, bool *isRestrict) {
  size_t bangLocation = usrString.find("#");
  if (bangLocation == std::string::npos || bangLocation == usrString.length() - 1) {
    *isVolatile = *isConst = *isRestrict = false;
    return;
  }
  bangLocation++;
  int x = usrString[bangLocation];

  *isConst = x & 0x1;
  *isVolatile = x & 0x4;
  *isRestrict = x & 0x2;
}
```

and in `main()`,

```
CXString usr = clang_getCursorUSR(cursor);
const char *usr_string = clang_getCString(usr);
std::cout << usr_string << "\n";
bool isVolatile, isConst, isRestrict;
parseUsrString(usr_string, &isVolatile, &isConst, &isRestrict);
printf("restrict, volatile, const: %d %d %d\n", isRestrict, isVolatile, isConst);
clang_disposeString(usr);
```

Running on `Foo::qux()` from

```
#define BLA const

class Foo {
public:
    void bar() const;
    void baz() volatile;
    void qux() BLA volatile;
};
```

produces the expected result of

```
c:@C@Foo@F@qux#5
restrict, volatile, const: 0 1 1
```

*Caveat*: you might have noticed that `libclang`'s source suggets my code should be `isVolatile = x & 0x2` and not `0x4`, so it might be the case you should replace 0x4 with 0x2. It's possible my implementation (OS X) has them replaced.

Comment: Does this work when the `const` or `volatile` qualifiers occur only after preprocessing?

Comment: No; libclang lexes the file you provide as is. You can solve this by running your file through a preprocessor before handing it to this code, i.e. `cpp bla.cpp > bla.cpp.pre`.

Comment: Added another solution which seems to work with preprocessing.

Comment: This was a very helpful comment - I couldn't figure out how to read `const` qualifiers in `clang.cindex`. However, it contains a subtle bug: you need to apply this logic to the byte after the *last*, not the *first*, `#` in the USR data. There could be multiple `#` if the function parameters or return value are `const`-qualified.

Comment: Also, in case anyone else stumbles upon this, this logic is now in `lib/Index/USRGeneration.cpp` in LLVM 3.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect pure virtual/const function using [clang_getCursorPrettyPrinted()](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__CURSOR__XREF.html#gab9d561cc237ce0d8bfbab80cdd5be216)
. This function gives you the method/function prototype in full (virtual, const, =0, etc. -- everything as you see in the source code). If you can get
a cursor for the desired function/method it's all you need. The answers from before show you how to get a cursor.

The code below is written in C++ but you can translate it to C because it uses libclang.

Example how to check for const method (getAsStdString is defined below):

```
auto funcPrettyPrinted = getAsStdString(
        clang_getCursorPrettyPrinted(cursor, nullptr));
if (std::string::npos != funcPrettyPrinted.find(") const"))
{
    break;
}
```

Example how to check for virtual function:

```
auto funcPrettyPrinted = getAsStdString(
        clang_getCursorPrettyPrinted(cursor, nullptr));
if (std::string::npos != funcPrettyPrinted.find("virtual") &&
    std::string::npos != funcPrettyPrinted.find("= 0"))
{
    break;
}
```

Here is an example of pretty printed output:

```
virtual void one() = 0
```

The less important but useful helper function:

```
std::string getAsStdString(CXString str)
{
    auto cstr = clang_getCString(str);
    if (nullptr == cstr)
    {
       return "";
    }
    std::string stdStr{cstr};
    clang_disposeString(str);
    return stdStr;
}
```

And of course you can use regex to make sure the searches are 100% correct... if you need to.